# Href not updating on localhost, linking to old files in browser

Tags: html

Href links to old/deleted files when I try to run the website on localhost.

I have checked for syntax errors, deleted my browser cache, refreshed the page, restarted apache, restarted xampp several times, even restarted my pc. Nothing seems to work.

// This is from inspect tool in my browser.

```
<a class="nav-icon" href="photo_home.html"><em class="fa fa-home"></em>
    <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

// This is the code in my text editor

```
<a class="nav-icon" href="home.php"><em class="fa fa-home"></em>
    <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

I expect the href from my text editor to work, but like I said, when I try to run the website on my localhost the href links to an old non-existing file in my directory. The home.php file is in the same directory as the file the above code is from.

Comment: My first guess is that in the browser, you're not looking at the file you're editing. Where is the html located inside `htdocs`? And what does it say in your address bar?

Comment: You're probably editing the wrong file and expecting it to change something it's not associated with.

Comment: @ChrisG The html is located in htdocs\appdev\projectname-git, and it my address bar it says: http://localhost/appdev/projectname-git/home.php

Comment: @tadman I've checked that I'm editing the same file, and that they're in the same directory.

Comment: Unless there's some weird `.htaccess` or virtual host business going on, I don't have an explanation. I'm still convinced you're looking at two different files essentially, because refreshing the browser is usually all it takes.

Comment: Despite what you think you're doing, your computer's configuration seems to dictate otherwise. Try making a new file and see if you can access it or not. If you can't you're probably editing in the wrong place.

Comment: I don't know. Try another browser maybe? What happens when you delete / move your home.php file and refresh the browser?

Comment: I made a beginners mistake and didn't include the header.php file to the other files that I was trying to access on the navbar. Thanks for your time. I learned my lesson.

Comment: Building the website like that isn't ideal anyway; in the long run you'll want to use your index.php file as basis for every page and include the main part based on a GET param. i.e. you'll have links like `index.php?page=contact` instead of `contact.php`.